# Checking if a file has been edited

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to know if there is a way to check if a file has been edited. I looked for methods that can make it for me on Google Apps library, but I have found nothing about it. I don't know if I searched wrong.

Basically, I need to take a file, take a measurable data (something like size) of this file and store on a variable. Then, I need to take that measurable data again, store on another variable,  and compare if there was a change. I need a boolean return.

Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following (pseudo with links to documentation):

1. Get the file you want to check using the [DocList Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/).
2. Get the ID of that File once you have it using [`File.getID()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#getId%28%29)
3. Get the last edit timestamp using [`File.getLastUpdated()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#getLastUpdated%28%29)
4. Store this value in a Spreadsheet, or maybe [Script or User Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/).
5. When you want to check to see if the File was updated, simply [`File.getFileById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/docs-list#getFileById%28String%29)
6. Repeat step 3.
7. Then compare the two last-edited timestamps with an operator like `!=`, or do more complex comparisons on the `Date`s if you want.
8. Depending on the result of step 7, return `true` or `false`.

Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/) is great, for all their services. You just need to read it a bit to understand what kind of power you have through scripting. Hopefully my pseudo-method helps in solving your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the file update date: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getLastUpdated() and for storing data look up the storing data section in the apps script help page.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the GAT General Audit Tool http://goo.gl/hzZ2yf... which reports when files were edited , viewed and much more.